# Django realtime updates with Firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase

I am currently trying to implement Firebase into my Django app with pattern 3 as indicated here (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html).

I am trying to have Firebase detect whenever the game model starts and to refresh all the other user's pages when this is done.

I am unable to find a good tutorial outlining how to do this so any tips at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you still interested in an answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I ended up using ajax to do this